# How to write to a text file in a blob container using Azure function with python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to run a timer trigger in Azure function which will write into my file saved in the blob storage container `output` as `log.txt`. Below is my **init**.py -

```
import datetime
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest, outputblob : func.Out[str]) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
    
    outputblob.set('some text')

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

below are the bindings for `function.json` -

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "dataType": "string",
      "path": "output/log.txt",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "out"
    }

  ]
}
```

Also this is the output of the log stream which I checked today, maybe this could help
[image: log_output]

The function is running but it is not writing anything to the `log.txt`. I am a beginner in the azure functions, so please pardon silly mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

This was working fine after reproducing from our end. Make sure you are adding the connection string of your storage account in local.settings.json. Also the corn expression in your timer function `0 */5 * * * *` runs 12 times an hour which means for every 5 mins a trigger is going to occur. so make sure you wait until the function gets triggered.

[image]

just to check if the result is getting reflected I have changed the corn expression to `5-7 * * * * *` which runs Three times a minute.

#### local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  }
}
```

#### Results:

[image]

### Updated Answer

#### local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "constr":"<CONNECTION STRING>"
  }
}
```

### function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "5-7 * * * * *"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "dataType": "string",
      "path": "container1/log.txt",
      "connection": "constr",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the file structure in my Function App.

[image]

Comment: I have some questions so that I can implement the same in my code. First, I have used visual studio code with azure extension to deploy it. When I created the timer trigger it did not generate any local.settings.json, so I have manually created and added the connection strings from the blob storage. Should it worked just fine as I am using or should I use any other way to deploy the function?

Comment: @Akash It has to work fine, also make sure you are using azure function in virtual environment as well. For creating an Azure function try navigating to **Azure >> Workspace >> Create Function** to create `local.settings.json` automatically. https://i.imgur.com/Exw4hRs.png

Comment: Another thing I wanted to ask what should I include in the connection string? Should I just copy paste the connection string from azure portal? or should I just use the `SAS` url? I am really getting overwhelmed here. Also In the logstream while checking for the verbose I can see `2022-07-12T05:50:00Z   [Verbose]   BlobWriteAccess - Name: output/log.txt, Type: BlockBlob/application/octet-stream, ETag: "0x8DA63CA5BD78AE0", WriteTime: 00:00:00.0001615, BytesWritten: 5` , Isnt this indicating the function is working fine?

Comment: @Akash, You can use the connection string from Azure portal directly and not the SAS URL. Also can you make sure that the string is not coping into the log.txt file?

Comment: can you help me out on that part? How to understand whether the string is coping into the log.txt file? Earlier I tried to do **Azure Portal** >> **My storage account name** >> **Access keys** >> **connection string for key 1** and copied it and pasted in the connection string.

Comment: You are doing it right @Akash , https://i.imgur.com/UFniv3T.png. To check whether the string is coping into the log.txt file just navigate to your blob and click on edit

Comment: Please try checking this image https://i.imgur.com/QPU0jVX.png

Comment: I have tried the updated one but it is throwing me error like [this](https://i.imgur.com/LjWgvkE.png)

Comment: This is my container [snapshot](https://i.imgur.com/9a3LncS.png).

Comment: FYI comments are not for long discussions, and these comments have indeed turned into a discussion. Please refrain from continuing this way. @Akash - I suggest removing all of these intermediate comments, and update your question accordingly to be clear about what works and what doesn't work. Also, just as important: **Please refrain from posting additional details in comments** under an answer - your latest comment even points to a screenshot. This is *definitely* not the way to go.

Comment: @DavidMakogon yah I know that part, couldn't help as my reputation isn't enough for discussion, and I was desperate for the help. Although it's pretty ugly it was my only way to understand and update my question as I am not well aware with this. I would gladly update all this when I will get an answer. For the time being I would just delete some of the comments that is not much of a relevance. Thank you.